# Where are the 3d analyst tools available in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, 3d-analyst

I want to know whether we can perform 3d analyst in Q-Gis? If yes, means where is that option present?

Comment: What kind of 3D stuff do you need.

Comment: @arun If your work is related with terrain data then you can Please check following link http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/03/working-with-terrain-data-in-qgis.html & Most of the times QGIS is better than ArcGIS : )

Comment: @ Nathan W i want to perform Raster math and Interpolation.

Comment: You have both a raster calculator and an Interpolation plugin.

Comment: i want to develope TIN from raster is it possible as in the case of ARC GIS?

Answer (score 1):

In 3D rasters, with three spatial dimensions plus a data value dimension, the point elements are called *voxels*. GRASS GIS provides [voxel operations](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/raster3dintro.html). Map algebra tools are provided in [r3.mapcalc](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r3.mapcalc.html).

If you are unfamiliar with how to set up QGIS to take advantage of these tools check out the [QGIS GRASS Cookbook](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/QGIS_GRASS_Cookbook), or for a more visual tutorial see [Setting Up A Working GRASS Environment in QGIS](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/01/setting-up-working-grass-environment-in.html).